# Problemas al instanciar un método de una clase

Tags: c#, clase

Hola os pongo en situación.
Tengo un archivo wsUsuarios.asmx que se encuentra en la carpeta ws dentro de otra carpeta que se llama admin (esta carpeta está a la misma altura que la carpeta App_Code donde hago lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace PortalMaestro.admin.ws
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class wsUsuarios : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        clsUsuarios claseUsuarios = new clsUsuarios();


        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string validarUserPwd(string sUsuario, string sPassword)
        {
            string paramSalida = string.Empty;



            paramSalida =  clsUsuarios.validarUserPwd(sUsuario, sPassword, out int idUsuario, out int idPerfil) 

            return paramSalida;
        }
```

Posteriormente tengo una clase clsUsuarios.cs que se encuentra en la carpeta App_Code y que tiene lo siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PortalMaestro.App_Code
{
    public class clsUsuarios
    {
        clsComunes claseComunes = new clsComunes();

        public string validarUserPwd(string sUsuario, string sPassword, out int idUsuario, out int idPerfil)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Con esta estructura no me permite acceder a los métodos de la clase clsUsuario.cs de la carpeta App_Code.

Alguien puede decirme que puede estar pasando para no poder llegar desde el asmx a la clase? Como podéis ver en clsUsuarios.cs hago algo muy similar instanciando la clase clsComunes la cual no provoca dicho error.

He probado a incluir la directiva using PortalMaestro.App_Code, pero tampoco ha funcionado.

Tiempo atrás, utilicé esta estructura y funcionó perfectamente pero tenía una carpeta ws donde tenía los asmx, y otra carpeta ws en App_Code donde tenía los asmx.cs.

Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: El asmx y la clase deben estar en la misma solución verifica que lo estén, si lo están debes agregar la referencia al namespace de tu clase clsUsuarios agregando using PortalMaestro.App_Code al asmx

Comment: Hola Victor, gracias por tu ayuda, por supuesto que el asmx y el cs están en la misma solución. Uno en la estructura PortalMaestro/admin/ws/.asmx y el otro en PortalMaestro/App_Code/.cs. Ya estoy completamente perdido. Estoy arrancando el proyecto y por algún motivo desde mis páginas (aspx) o desde los webservices(asmx) no veo las clases.
He creado la página index en la raíz del proyecto y le agregué el using PortalMaestro y aún así no veo ninguna de los .cs que tengo dentro de App_Code. Sin embargo, si creo un archivo .cs fuera de App_Code si que se visualiza correctamente.

Comment: agrega la referencia en tu asmx no la tienes using PortalMaestro.App_Code y luego recompilas.

Comment: Creo que tu problema es que no haz agregado la referencia web a tu proyecto.

Comment: Pero con esta última opción, ni siquiera me aparece la opción App_Code, como puedes ver en la imagen adjunta (http://prntscr.com/kp6l5t) en la nueva página que está en admin(index.aspx) ni siquiera me permite agregar la referencia a PortalMaestro.App_Code en el aspx.

Comment: Vale, creo que ya entiendo el problema... Antes trabajaba con sitios web, y ahora lo estoy haciendo con una aplicación web. Por lo que he leído la app compila el contenido de App_Code (ahí es donde dices que crees que falta la referencia web), como tendría que agregarla?

Comment: Es en el webservice (asmx) que debes hacer referencia al namespace de la clase y la referencia web se agrega haciendo click derecho encima de tu solución y dandole a la opción agregar referencia web ahi colocas la dirección de tu asmx

Comment: Muchas gracias Victor, perdona la tardanza, al final lo conseguí. El problema se solventó al crear otra carpeta (con nombre Code) y crear las clases ahí... ahora ya puedo instanciarlas perfectamente. Por lo que estuve viendo, tiene que ver porque estaba usando el concepto Sitio Web, y el proyecto que creé era una aplicación web, eso fue lo que me dio la pauta para hacer pruebas y resolver el problema. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda y por tu tiempo.